# table tr:first-child td - not working properly

Tags: css, css-selectors, border

I am using CSS with tables to put the fraction line between the numerator and the denominator. For a complex fraction, it is not working properly on ant browser. Below is sample code use in the try it editor that shows the problem. Under the letter C there is an unwanted border. But the letter F, coded similarly is OK. I tried 4 browsers, all had the same problem. There is a workaround of adding style="border:none" to the problem < td > (adding a class doesn't work), but why do I need to do that?
PS. Yes I know about < Math > but is too unwieldy for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table   {display:inline-table; vertical-align:middle}
table tr:first-child td {border-bottom:solid black}
td  {vertical-align:middle>
</style>
</head>
<body>
V = <table>
<tr>    <td>A + <table>
            <tr>    <td>B</td></tr>
           <tr> <td>C</td></tr></table></td></tr>
    <tr>    <td>D + <table>
            <tr>    <td>E</td></tr>
            <tr>    <td>F</td></tr></table>
</td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are targetting all td elements within a tr element that is a first child.

The C is within the very first tr in the outer table and so gets targeted, despite the fact it is also within another table and tr.

If you get a bit more specific, ensure that only those tds that are direct children of a first-child tr are selected, then the C loses its underline.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
      table {
      display: inline-table;
      vertical-align: middle
    }
    
    table tr:first-child>td {
      border-bottom: solid black
    }
    
    td {
      vertical-align: middle>
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  V =
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>A +
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>B</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>C</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>D +
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>E</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>F</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No, the C is not a part of the first < tr > of the table. You need to explain why the C was underlined and the F was not.

Comment: The C is in the first tr of the first table so gets selected. It is also within another table within that tr but that doesn’t stop it being in the very first tr.